# How to increase phpmyadmin upload file size

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am not able to change the file size that phpmyadmin accepts for importing databases on my test server.

I have changed all values I have some idea about in `my.cnf`:

```
max_packet_size
Key_buffer
```

or the upload file size and
`max_post_size` value in every `php.ini` file I have found on the system.

The accepted file size on the import screen still remains 8,192kib.

Comment: As per reference of [increase MySQL import file size](http://guruquest.net/question/increase-mysql-phpmyadmin-import-file-size-in-ubuntu-16-04/) by usage of a terminal of ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first things to check (or ask your host provider to check) are the values of `max_execution_time`, `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size` in the php.ini configuration file. All of these three settings limit the maximum size of data that can be submitted and handled by PHP.

Please note that `post_max_size` needs to be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 36):

To [increase MySQL phpmyadmin import file size in Ubuntu](http://guruquest.net/question/increase-mysql-phpmyadmin-import-file-size-in-ubuntu-16-04/) 16.04 or newer, follow these steps. In the newest Ubuntu version you can have either PHP 5 or PHP 7.

Step - 1: open `php.ini` of the appropriate PHP version(s).

- For PHP v5.0

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
  ```
- For PHP v7.0

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
  ```
- For PHP v7.1

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
  ```
- For PHP v7.2

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
  ```
- For PHP v7.3

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini
  ```

Step - 2: Now need to increase below parameters in the `php.ini` file.

```
memory_limit = 1500M

post_max_size = 1500M

upload_max_filesize = 1500M
```

Please Note : post_max_size should be larger than upload_max_size

Step - 3: Now you need to restart your apache server to effect changes.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Someone else tried to leave this as a comment in response to this answer: "Note it is actually mentioned above but when I inserted 1500Mb it didn't worked.My localhost got out of the order. It should 1500m not 1500mb ;)"

Answer (score 7):

1. create info.php page and check all details  about file

   ```
   <?php 
     phpinfo();
   ?>
   ```
2. run in your browser search **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size** change by default value **2M to 80M.**
3. Run

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
   ```
4. change both values `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`
   change by default value `2M` to `80M`
5. Restart apache

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Set the variables `upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, memory_limit` in php.ini to the right values and restart the server, then it should work.
If it does not work, check with `phpinfo()` if you edited the right php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

If In case you are using Virtualmin , Webmin or Usermin  then

Follow below 2 steps as per image:
1.
[image: step 1 image]

2.
[image: step 1 image]